# Defining arguments for Kalman filter in R

Tags: r, kalman-filter

I have been trying to figure out how to define the equations and arguments to run a Kalman filter (fkf package) with 4 variables. The model I am working with is an extended capital asset pricing model, and the variables are the dependent variable: Rpt (excess portfolio return) and three independent variables: Rmt (excelss monthly return), SMB (size factor), and ILLIQ (illiquidity factor). The data consists of monthly data for 22 stocks for 5 years running. The link gives an idea of how the data set looks, for ease of reference. [Portfolio returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGDLY.png). Here is the dataset with the first three stocks: [3 first stocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muy3a.png)

Loading the above dataset (in full), I have been able to run the Kalman filter with only one variable, Rpt above. However, how do I add more variables to the model? I am struggling with defining the correct arguments and equations. Can anyone help with this? Below is the code I have so far.

```
namibia1 <- read.delim(file.choose(), header=T)
attach(namibia1)
namibia1_ts <- ts(as.numeric(namibia1[,1]), frequency=12, start=c(2011,1), end=c(2015,12))
namibia1_ts <- ts(as.numeric(namibia1[,1]), frequency=12, start=c(2011,1), end=c(2015,12))
y <- namibia1_ts
dt <- ct <- matrix(0)
Tt <- matrix(1)
a0 <- y[1]
P0 <- matrix(1)
Zt <- matrix(c(1), ncol=60)
fit.fkf <- optim(c(HHt = var(y, na.rm=TRUE)*.5, 
                   GGt = var(y, na.rm=TRUE)*.5), 
                   fn  = function(par, ...){ -fkf(HHt = matrix(par[1]) }, 
                   GGt = matrix(par[2]), ...)$logLik, 
                   yt  = rbind(y), 
                   a0 = a0, P0 = P0, dt = dt, ct = ct, Zt = Zt, Tt = Tt, 
                  check.input = FALSE)
```

What I am struggle with more precisely is how to define the transition and measurement equation as matrixes, and if so, how? This may seem like a very easy thing to do, but so far it hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When number of explanatory variable is one, the measurement and transition equation are:
[image]
In this image, [ 1  Xt ] is `Zt`, νt's error is `GGt`. `diag(2)` is Tt. Above image and I assume no intercept, so `ct = matrix(0)` and `dt <- matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=1)`. Estimated `c(μ0, β0)` is `a0` and it's variance is `P0`.

```
# using data
namibia1 <- data.frame(Rpt = c(-7.9466, 7.0845, -6.4460, 5.0913, -0.1614, 10.4113, 11.5786, 
                              -6.6402, -6.9760, -0.7926, 7.2900, 16.1156, -12.1467),
                      Rmt = c(-2.9151, -2.6468, -3.5493, -2.9928, -1.8305, -1.8491, -3.2975,
                              -0.9582, -4.1794, -5.0553, 1.8858, -1.4464, -2.9151),
                      SMB = c(-2.5471, -4.3690, 4.2772, 12.1632, 5.1860, -5.3839, -1.4868, 
                              12.1463, 10.8383, 8.4175, -11.1109, -32.2698, -0.5691),
                      ILLIQ = c(-1.7851, 18.3652, -3.2890, 4.9808, -13.8678, -2.9312, 18.5644,
                                -2.6254, -23.1361, 3.2620, -8.3979, 37.6330, 14.7067),
                      Year = c(rep(2011, 12), 2012),
                      Month = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "Juli", "August",
                                "September", "October", "November", "December", "Janualy"))

# In your equations, m = 4, d = 1, n = nrow(namibia1)
y <- namibia1$Rpt
dt <- matrix(0, nrow=4, ncol=1)
ct <- matrix(0)
Tt <- diag(4)
Zt <- array(t(cbind(rep(1,nrow(namibia1)), namibia1[,2:4])), dim=c(1, 4, nrow(namibia1)))
a0 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1)
P0 <- matrix(100, nrow=4, ncol=4)

fit.fkf <- optim(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 fn = function(par, ...) -fkf(HHt = diag(4) * par[1:4], GGt = matrix(par[5]), ...)$logLik,
                 yt = rbind(y), a0 = a0, P0 = P0, dt = dt, ct = ct,
                 Zt = Zt, Tt = Tt, check.input = T)
sqrt(fit.fkf$par) # estimated sd
fkf.obj <- fkf(a0, P0, dt, ct, Tt, Zt, HHt = diag(4) * fit.fkf$par[1:4],
               GGt = matrix(fit.fkf$par[5]), yt = rbind(y))
# the value of a0, P0 and optim's par mean nothing special.
```

#### Edited (Sorry, I forgot slope.)

```
estimatedLevel <- fkf.obj$att[1,] + namibia1[,2] * fkf.obj$att[2,] + namibia1[,3] * fkf.obj$att[3,] + namibia1[,4] * fkf.obj$att[4,]

plot(y)
lines(estimatedLevel, col = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the above! Much appreciated. This seems to be correct with one stock. I have added another link with the first three stocks. Note how the identier under "Stock" is the same for the first 12, then changes for the next 12, and so. How can I update the above code, so that all 22 stocks can be included for the 5 (2011-2015) years of data?

Comment: You want the 22 results, aren't you? You'll make 22 data.frames that have 5 years data and use the above code to all of them. Update points are only data.frame's name (namibial1 in above code) and result object's name. If the column number change,  modify `Zt <- ... namibia1[,2:4]` 's `2:4` (e.g.; `3:5`; `c(2,4,5)`).

Comment: I was actually hoping to get one coefficient for each variable, if possible. Something I can compare with the coefficients of my OLS regressions (not included here). I see you have listed the dimensions, but since I have 22 stocks (each with monthly observations), shouldn't d = 22? Also, since I have seven more datasets, I was hoping to get one string of code, easily adjusted and ready to use for all eight data sets. The column number is the same in all of the datasets. However, the number of stocks differ. Would it be possible to design such a code?

Comment: This method calculate intercept and each variable's coefficients every time points. `fkf.obj$att`'s 1st row is intercept, 2nd row is Rmt's coefficient, and so on. Sorry, I don't know it because I've done fkf with only d = 1.